# Change indent tab size in website created by Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have just built a website with Jekyll, the code can be found [here](https://github.com/cwangblog/cwangblog.github.io), and in one page [here](http://cwangblog.github.io/programming/2016/05/25/lua-and-torch-useful-materials), it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the indent tab size in code block is 8 instead of 4, however, I would like to change it into 4. How?

Answer (score 1):

The loop with the red arrow is using tabs for indenting the code. The loops that are below that use double spaces for indenting.

In your code block, swap the tabs for four spaces and it will display consistently on your page.